# In this case, how to map this json to model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, github-mantle

Here is a json:

```
{
  query_list: [
    {
      restaurant: {},
      foods: [
        food1: {},
        food2: {}
      ]
    },
    {
      restaurant: {},
      foods: [
        food3: {},
        food4: {}
      ]
    }
  ],
  url: ""
}
```

I want use Mantle to map it to:

```
@property NSString *url
@property NSArray<Foods *> *list
```

the `list` need to contains all foods. In this case, foods are `food1` `food2` `food3` `food4`.

So how to get all `foods`, combine them to a new array which map to the property `list`

Comment: Why is query_list  a dictionary  but  contains "restaurant array" ???

Comment: @QunLi `query_list` is a array, but i only need all `foods` which are nested in every `query_list` element

Comment: merito your `foods` array is with key `food1,food2,food3..` or you  have just added that for reference ?

Comment: @CodeChanger just add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your JSON formate you have to done below thing to get all food object in single list :

```
 NSMutableArray * mutArrayFoods = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for (QueryList *objQueryList in objParseData.queryList) {
      [mutArrayFoods addObjectsFromArray:objQueryList.foods];
 }
```

Hope this will help to get all foods in single array.

Now as per your request assign this above array into `list`

```
list = [mutArrayFoods mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

I change your "Pseudo json code"  many times. Maybe your thinking like this:

[image]

I try my best to create a model called "HF" for helping you:
[image]

[image]